# ambari (hortonworks ) not showing Hive View

Tags: hive, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I am new in HortonWorks and Ambari, I was watching some tutorials and in that tutorials I see the Views -> Hive Views, but my installation only has Yarn Queue Manager, Files View and Workflow Manager.
I am using Admin user (in user setting says "This is user is an Ambari Admin and has all privileges".

Please could you advise if I need to configure some else to see all options?

Answer (score 0):

@West14 depending on the version of Ambari you will not see a Hive View.  The Hive View is HDP2.     The Hive View is no longer part of HDP3.

An alternative to Hive View for HDP3 is Hue.